# Rails Rails_API Gem convention generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api

Is there a way to create a convention for my app? I would like to do something like `get '*/:id' => '*Controller#GET'` in my `routes.rb`, in order to establish that any GET request will be handled by a GET method in a class in the controllers folder that matches the name composition...

I would also do that for all others HTTP verbs...

My problem right now is that im planning a REST API that will have dozens of controllers and I don't want to maintain a huge routes file... according to my calculations, if i can't get this going, there will be over 400 entries in my routes only for the first version of the API...

Comment: Do you know beforehand the names of the controllers?

Comment: Also: have you read the official doc on [wildcards](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments)?

Comment: @brito yes I did, but its definitive... i can't wildcard the "to"...

Comment: did you try out my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the resources beforehand, you can iteratively define the endpoints in `routes.rb`. Suppose you want to define the resources `foo` and `foobar` to their respective controllers. Adding the following:

```
  ['foo', 'foobar'].each do |resource|
    resources resource.to_sym, controller: "#{resource}/"
  end
```

will create the appropriate routes:

```
$ rake routes | grep foo
                      foo_index GET    /foo(.:format)                                                                             foo/#index
                                POST   /foo(.:format)                                                                             foo/#create
                        new_foo GET    /foo/new(.:format)                                                                         foo/#new
                       edit_foo GET    /foo/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                    foo/#edit
...
```

Of course, if you want a specific verb, it would suffice to change `resources resource.to_sym, controller: "#{resource}/"` to, say, `get "#{resource}/:id" => '#{resource}Controller#GET'`.

Since you mentioned you would have hundreds of resources (in contrast with the trivial `['foo', 'foobar']` example), you could even define them externally (e.g. in a `YAML` file) and load them in `routes.rb`.